# Laravel @extends('layouts.app') not working on some pages

Tags: php, laravel, extends

@extends('layouts.app')
does not work on some of my web pages. it just shows the content without the layout. why is this happening?

I already tried making a new layout folder and calling it but still some pages still doesn't show the layout.

[both show.blade.php and create.blade.php doesn't display the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCMn3.png)

[it only shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwlSj.png)

[app.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxaLF.png)
[this is  the navbar.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrQYt.png)

Comment: Adding more code could help

Comment: did you place the code within the @section

Comment: php artisan view:clear

Comment: can you share the bit of code

Comment: THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T SHOW THE LAYOUT....@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <a href = "/posts" class ="btn btn-default">Return</a>
    <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
    
    <div>
            {{$post->body}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <small> Posted on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
@endsection

Comment: php artisan view:clear did not fix my problem. :(

Comment: do make sure app is in the layout directory and the layout directory is in the views directory

Comment: yes. it is in the views/layouts/app.blade.php

Comment: send us the layout.app code itself

Comment: @jediArvin  Please share your full code with file location i am damm sure issue on name of file or location of file.

Comment: i added some pics.

Comment: already solved. it was just the CSS file. thanks to all of you! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS file maybe not loading properly.

change your `app.blade.php` file like below,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/css/app.css" >
```

Comment: THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

you might what to try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this fixed it (had to add public):

href="{{ asset('public/css/app.css')

Answer (score 0):

If your style css not working on every page, try adding it with the asset helper;

This help me to solve exactly the same problem. You can find in Laravel Docs. ;
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).